# enforcing specific date format in java

Tags: java, validation, date

In my java program a java variable `String inputDate` accepts input form user. I want to enforce users to enter date in (dd/MM/yyyy) format only as my other modules depend on that format only. Here's what I tried so far:

```
public class InputQuery {

private static String FLIGHT_DATE;

public String getFLIGHT_DATE() {
    return FLIGHT_DATE;
}

public void setFLIGHT_DATE() {

    boolean invalid = true;
    Scanner sc = null;
    while(invalid){
        System.out.println("Enter FLIGHT_DATE(dd/MM/yyy) :");
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        FLIGHT_DATE = sc.nextLine();
        if( (invalid = isValidDate(FLIGHT_DATE)) ) {
            System.out.println("For Feb 21,2016 enter 21/02/2016");
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}

private boolean isValidDate(String flight_DATE) {
    SimpleDateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    if( flightDate.parse(flight_DATE)){
       System.out.println("accepted OK");
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ok. What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: one you do parse and no exceptions are caught (if it cant parse it throws an exception) and store it in a variable .. parse method will return !

Answer (score 1):

Use `myDateFormat.setLenient(false)`.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    try{
        sdf.parse(incomingDateString);
        // if you get here, the incomingDateString is valid
    }catch(ParseException ex){
        // if you get here, the incomingDateString is invalid
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work, try this

```
private boolean isValidDate(String flightDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    myDateFormat.setLenient(false);
    try {
        myDateFormat.parse(flightDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println("accepted OK");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Leniency is `false` by default for the `parse()` method (it's `true` by default for the other flavour of `parse`, which accepts a `ParsePosition`).

Comment: try SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");System.out.println(df.isLenient());

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, what you'd like to do is to ensure that the date entered corresponds to the format.

The `parse(String)` method doesn't return a boolean, and it never returns `null`. If it's successful, it returns a date; if it's unsuccessful, it throws an exception. The way to do this is:

```
private boolean isValidDate(String flight_DATE) {
    SimpleDateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        myDateFormat.parse(flight_DATE);
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        // You may want to print the exception here, or do something else with it
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to check given input is in format or not try this:

```
public class DateValidator {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String flightDate = null;
        boolean isDateValid = false;

        while(!isDateValid){
            System.out.print("Enter FLIGHT_DATE(dd/MM/yyy) :");
            flightDate = scanner.nextLine().trim();
            isDateValid = isDateValid(flightDate);
            if(!isDateValid){
                System.out.println("Wrong Format.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("continue.");
    }

    public static boolean isDateValid(String flightDate){
        String regex = "^\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(flightDate);
        return matcher.find();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, d in `String regex = "^\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}$";` is for Integer.
but 78/78/1256 is also identified as valid date.(!!!)